# What is a Maclaurin series for $(x^2 + x + 1)^p$

Tags: calculus

> Find the Maclaurin series for $(x^2 + x + 1)^p$.

I know that for $(x+1)^p$ it is sum from $k = 0$ to infinity of $ \binom{p}{k}x^k$, but I can't figure out $(x^2 + x + 1)^p$ without just saying that it is $\binom{p}{k}(x^2 + x)^k$, which is not a Maclaurin series as it does not have an $x^k$ term.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. By your remark,
$$((x^2 + x) + 1)^p=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{p}{k}(x^2 + x)^k+o(x^n).$$
Now, expand $(x^2 + x)^k$ as $x^k\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}x^j$.
Hence the coefficient of $x^n$ in the Maclaurin expansion of $((x^2 + x) + 1)^p$ can be obtained by summing the coefficients of $x^{k+j}$ such that $k+j=n$:
$$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{p}{k}\binom{k}{n-k}.$$

Comment: OK, thanks, but I tried that and my brother pointed out that your coefficient on you $x^k$ term is $\binom{p}{k}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}x^j$ which has an $x$ in it. you can' put $x$ in your constant.

Comment: I am not saying that the coefficient of $x^k$ is $\binom{p}{k}\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}x^j$... See my edited answer.

Comment: OK. I did it that way myself and came to the same conclusion but the coefficient on $x^n$ was $\sum_{n-k=0}^n\binom{k}{n-k}\binom{p}{k}$.

Comment: This makes the total function $\sum_{n=0}^{2p}\sum_{n-k=0}^n\binom{k}{n-k}\binom{p}{k}x^n$

Comment: Is this possible for a non-integer p?

Comment: For non-integer $p$, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k}{n-k}\binom{p}{k}x^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach.

$$\begin{align}
(x^2+x+1)^p &= \left( \frac{1-x^3}{1-x} \right)^p \\
&= (1-x^3)^p \cdot (1-x)^{-p} \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i \binom{p}{i} x^{3i} \cdot \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \binom{p+j-1}{j} x^j
\end{align}$$
We have applied the Binomial Theorem (twice) in the last equation above.

So the coefficient of $x^n$ in $(x^2+x+1)^p$ is
$$\sum_{3i+j=n} (-1)^i \binom{p}{i} \binom{p+j-1}{j} =\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor n/3 \rfloor} (-1)^i \binom{p}{i} \binom{p+n-3i-1}{n-3i}$$
for $n = 0,1,2, \dots ,2p$.